# explain why geometry nodes positioning is acting more like scaling

Tags: geometry-nodes

Im struggling somewhat with geometry nodes to understand why some attributes work the way they do. In this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nFtRnBErnmw&t=330s around minute 3:30 it shows how the capture attribute of position is going down to the center point of the geometry.  Then pulling the value directly from the position node shows the position of the original mesh.  What does running the position node through the capture attribute node do? Why when you mix them instead of moving the hexagons between the outer and center position it is scaling them? When I attach the viewer node to any of the position or store attribute I get an empty list in the spreadsheet screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Capture Attribute

> This node is essential because field input nodes like the Position Node work in the context of the node they are connected to. [(Official Blender documentation)](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/attribute/capture_attribute.html)

Without a *Capture Attribute*, the input node *Position* will return the position of each vertex/edge/face (depends on the context).

By passing the *Position* through a *Capture Attribute* set on *Face*, you are now getting the position of the face, which is the same for all 5 or 6 vertices of the face.

So, for each vertex, by mixing between the position of the vertex and the position of the face to which it belongs, you are attracting all 5 or 6 vertices to the center of the face. You are only playing between [position of vertices] and [position of face].

Here is a visualisation for one face, where face position is shown by cones.

[image: Example of what the example is doing]

So in your example, you are *capturing* the position of the face and using it on vertices.

#### Your questions

> What does running the position node through the capture attribute node do ?

You are explicitly asking to get the *Position* from the point of view of a certain *Domain* (here, *Face*).

> Why when you mix them instead of moving the hexagons between the outer and center position it is scaling them ?

You are not mixing between [vertex position] and [origin], but between [vertex position] and [face position]. You are only repositioning the vertices but you are correct, it *is* identical to scaling faces.

> When I attach the viewer node to any of the position or store attribute I get an empty list in the spreadsheet screen.

You can set your *Viewer* to any *Domain* you want : face, vertex, ... Default is automatic and doesn't always give you what you are expecting.

Comment: Thank you.  This cleared up a good bit.  When you explained that repositioning the vertices was what was being done with the set position that cleared up a lot.

Answer (score 1):

*(Using Blender 3.6.8)*

Following is a step by step explanation of what is going on in the referenced video, with a simplified geometry. In particular, using a *Separate Geometry* node, only the first face (of *Index* 0) is kept.

**1.** The Spreadsheet shows the position of the 5 vertices.

[image: Initial face]

**2.** The [*Capture Attribute*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/attribute/capture_attribute.html) node set in *Face* domain is recovering the position of the face, i.e. its barycentre, the mean position of its 5 vertices. This value can be displayed in the Spreadsheet using a *Viewer* node, here conveniently set also in *Face* domain.

[image: Face position]

**3.** The [*Set Position*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/geometry/write/set_position.html) node is modifying the vertices position, not the face position. So if the *Attribute* socket of the *Capture Attribute* node is connected to the *Position* socket of the *Set Position* node, the vertices position is set to the face position they belong. As a consequence, they all collapse at the face barycentre, as shown in the Spreadsheet, not at the object origin. The face is invisible, because its area is null.

[image: Set position node with face position]

**4.** *(NB: instead of using a *Mix* node, the following graph is taking advantage of the *Offset* socket of the *Set Position* node)*. To move the face, the position of its vertices is shifted by the *Set Position* node. The shifting direction is defined as the vector going from the object origin (i.e. the origin of coordinates inside a *Geometry Nodes* modifier) to the face barycentre. The shifting amplitude is defined as a fraction of this vector, controlled by the *Scale* node (a *Vector Math* node). Both faces are joined together to be displayed in the Spreadsheet. The first 5 vertices are the unmodified ones. The last 5 vertices are the shifted ones. With this particular face, the shifting direction is -Z, simplifying the analysis.

[image: Face shifted]

Resources: [image]

Comment: Thank you, this explained a lot but was not as clear as the other answer.